# Valid usage of OpAmp for current sensing with motor driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, pcb-design, dc-motor, current-sensing, rp2040

I am working on a custom PCB that can perform position control using 3 DC motors. One of the functionalities that I am trying to implement is stall detection and current limiting. I closely followed the instructions of both the OpAmp and motor driver datasheets, and would like to ask if I understood it correctly. I am working with a Raspberry Pi RP2040, TI DRV8231DSGR motor driver, and TLV9001IDCKR OpAmp on a custom PCB design.

The goal is to use the current sensing and current limiting capabilities from the motor driver, amplify it to a voltage of max 3.3v, and feed it to the RP2040. The current limiter should kick in at 1A.

My design parameters are as follows:
[image: Design parameters]

Both the analog and digital reference voltages are 3.3V.

The 330mOhm resistor is based on the formula from the TI datasheet:
[image]

Then the parts are connected in the following way:

**Motor Driver (3x)**
DRV8231 with ISEN(current sensing/limiting pin) connected to GND via a 330mOhm resistor
[image: Motor Driver]

**OpAmp (3x)**
Uses ISEN(current sensing/limiting pin) as input to amplify for RP2040
[image: OpAmp]

**RP2040**
Inputs the amplified signal into one of the analog input pins.
[image: RP2040]

Did I approach this setup correctly? In an early test build of the PCB I could not get the current sensing signal to provide anything other than noise to the RP2040. This could either be a design or soldering issue, and I am trying to pinpoint the cause. Is there maybe any feedback on my setup that could help resolve the problem?
And a specific question: are the values for R31 and R30 on the OpAmp realistic for my use case?

Any input is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

For convenience, a link to the datasheets that I have used:

- DRV8231: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/drv8231
- TLV9001: https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlv9001